# I want to get the values from URL parameter contain special characters

Tags: javascript, jsp

URL:

```
http://localhost:9091/tetdomain/landing/home?module=test&amp;value=654138
```

Now below is JSP code:

```
localStorage.setItem('ls.module', '${param.module}');
localStorage.setItem('ls.Value', '${param.'amp;otp'}');   //giving error as special character
```

Please let me know if any other solution to fetch the value

Expected value: `654138`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using javascript in a web-browser, and your url is:
http://localhost:9091/tetdomain/landing/home?module=test&value=654138

You can use javascript in browser to fetch the value using:

```
var queryString = window.location.search;
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
var value = searchParams.get("value");
```

then value == "654138"